# Extract values from XML - Xpath or direct parse?

Tags: xml

Trying to figure out the right approach to extract content from a complex XML. Using Keywords, I'm trying to identify and extract using Xpath. I need to extract 50+ attributes an XML generated from a PDF document. (Saved as XML)
Now, I'm wondering if this is the right way?.

Should I be parsing the XML using a DOM parser perhaps and then extracting whatever I need?  Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. You should start accepting some of the answers to your previous questions.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering about the previous questions myself as well.How do I "accept" an answer? Didn't see a link to accept or close the questions.

Comment: Just click on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't use DOM. Assuming you're in the Java world (you don't actually say), use one of the more modern tree models such as XOM or JDOM2. They are much easier to work with, especially when using namespaces, they are faster, and they support all the functionality you need. People use DOM because they don't realise there is anything better.

Secondly, using a tree model and using XPath are not mutually exclusive. I will quite often build the tree and then do a mixture of XPath navigation and direct navigation: for example find an element using XPath, then access its attributes using direct navigation. XPath makes the more complex access paths much easier to express, and the resulting code is more maintainable, but I wouldn't use XPath just to get from an element to one of its attributes.

Whatever approach you use (DOM, SAX, XPath, data binding), getting data from XML into Java is a hassle. If you can avoid it, by writing the whole application in an XML-based language such as XSLT or XQuery, then do.

Answer (score 0):

"right" how? "right" for who? As a coder? As performance? Which "right" are you looking for?

Most likely, XPath will be the most elegant:

```
thing = getPathThing(doc, "/path/to/element");
<repeat 50 times>
```

It will likely be the slowest. It simply has to do the most work.

The DOM technique will, potentially, be slightly faster. Both walk the DOM to find their elements. I'm sure the difference is measurable, I'm not sure it's noticeable, not if all of the XPath expressions are precompiled. Both require the entire document to be in memory.

The fastest method is running some streaming parser (i.e. SAX), since you can grab the elements as they fly by. SAX parsers tend to be awful to look at, however. We have the other mechanisms for a reason, SAX is not particularly elegant at all. But it is fast, and memory cheap. Its memory cost is relative to the data you keep, not the total data of the XML payload.

If you can "afford it", XPath is likely your best bet from a code maintainability POV, otherwise I'd bear down and go SAX.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, do realise "right" is subjective. I was just wondering if Xpath is the recommended approach if all I'm doing is a simple search and extract. In my case, processing speed is not an issue but accuracy is. Fairly sure Xpath is the right approach for my requirement, but wanted to be certain that this is a n acceptable way.